# DateTime to Hex and reverse without conversion to Int64

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

I need to convert `DateTime` to Hex string, as Hex string to `DateTime`.

My conversion from `DateTime` to Hex `Convert.ToInt64(dt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")).ToString("X2")` converts `DateTime` to `String` to `Int64` to `String`.
Is it possible to simplify this method by avoiding multiple conversion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is `Int64/long` and that you can use for `Hex` string like:

```
string hexString = dt.Ticks.ToString("X2");
```

To get the `DateTime` back you can do:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt64(hexString, 16));
```